# Passing an array from Ajax to PHP

Tags: javascript, php, arrays, ajax, json

I'm a newbie in ajax,  I've created this array through a function in js from a btn table: I've tried it many ways with no success, there's nothing printed in my *.php.. even with `print_r`, `var__dump`, etc

console.log(data)

```
{"datos":[{"value":false,"id":"173"},{"value":false,"id":"172"},{"value":false,"id":"171"},{"value":false,"id":"170"}]}
```

big question is: How can I pass this array to php, because I need to update a table sql with those values

JS:

```
$('#update').click(function(e){
e.preventDefault();
var datos = [],
    data = '',
    checkStatus = document.getElementsByName('check');

    for(var i=0;i<checkStatus.length;i++){
        var item = {
            "value": checkStatus[i].checked,
            "id": checkStatus[i].getAttribute('data-id')
        } 
        datos.push(item);
    }
    data = JSON.stringify({datos:datos});

$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "updateTable.php",
    datatype: "json",
    data: {data}, 
    cache: false,

    success: function(){
        console.log(data);
    }
});
});
```

PHP:

????????

Comment: Well, you'd pass the array like any other variable. You'd have work in the `PHP` extracting the data. But as far as passing it goes, you pass the `array variable` name in the `data` section.

Comment: "I've tried it many ways" did you try `var_dump($_POST);` ?

Comment: start with `print_r( json_decode( $_POST['data'], true ) );`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On the server side ..

```
 var_dump(json_decode($json));
```

or for each

```
 $json = '{"foo-bar": 12345}';

 $obj = json_decode($json);
 print $obj->{'foo-bar'}; // 12345
```